# Deploying Spring Boot App to Google App Engine - issues with connecting to SQL instance (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-platform

I have a Gradle based Spring Boot app that I'm trying to deploy to the App Engine via the App Engine gradle plugin. The SQL instance (PostgreSQL) is up and running fine, I can connect to it locally through DataGrip and it works fine. Here's my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#################### GOOGLE CLOUD SETTINGS
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=db-name
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=app-name:europe-west2:db-name
```

When I try to deploy the app, I'm getting the following error (seems that it can't connect to the SQL instance):

```
A 2020-05-27T16:12:26.340839Z 2020-05-27 16:12:26.340  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Default POSTGRESQL JdbcUrl provider. Connecting to jdbc:postgresql://google/db-name?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=instance-name:europe-west2:db-name with driver org.postgresql.Driver 
A 2020-05-27T16:12:26.773138Z 2020-05-27 16:12:26.772  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 
A 2020-05-27T16:12:26.977687Z 2020-05-27 16:12:26.977  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final 
A 2020-05-27T16:12:27.413333Z 2020-05-27 16:12:27.413  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final} 
A 2020-05-27T16:12:27.683594Z 2020-05-27 16:12:27.683  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting... 
A 2020-05-27T16:12:27.760810Z 2020-05-27 16:12:27.760  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [app-name:europe-west2:db-name] via unix socket. 
A 2020-05-27T16:12:27.966435Z 2020-05-27 16:12:27.966  WARN 10 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor, but class was expected 
2020-05-27 17:12:27.970 BST
2020-05-27 16:12:27.970 INFO 10 --- [ main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

I've researched this issue and it seems that this happens when the runtime classpath is different the compile class path. Problem is that I can't reproduce it locally and I can't figure out if it's a dependency that's causing this.

Full stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor, but class was expected

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean (AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization (AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1226)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1215)
        at com.turbochargedapps.basketballappinternalrest.BasketballAppInternalRestApplication.main (BasketballAppInternalRestApplication.java:21)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run (MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main (JarLauncher.java:52)

Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor, but class was expected

        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.generateInterfaceImpl (AsmLibraryLoader.java:104)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.loadLibrary (AsmLibraryLoader.java:89)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary (NativeLibraryLoader.java:44)
        at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load (LibraryLoader.java:325)
        at jnr.unixsocket.Native.<clinit> (Native.java:80)
        at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.<init> (UnixSocketChannel.java:101)
        at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.open (UnixSocketChannel.java:65)
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.connect (CoreSocketFactory.java:180)
        at com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory.createSocket (SocketFactory.java:71)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init> (PGStream.java:73)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect (ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:93)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl (ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection (ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init> (PgConnection.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection (Driver.java:459)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect (Driver.java:261)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection (DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection (PoolBase.java:358)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry (PoolBase.java:206)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry (HikariPool.java:477)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast (HikariPool.java:560)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init> (HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection (HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection (DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection (JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService (JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService (JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService (StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService (AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService (AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService (AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices (DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies (AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService (AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService (AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init> (InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete (MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata (EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build (EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory (SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory (LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory (AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet (AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet (LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
```

build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.2.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.8'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

appengine {
    deploy {
        appengine.deploy.version = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
        appengine.deploy.projectId = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
    }
}

group = 'com.group'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('snippetsDir', file("build/generated-snippets"))
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR4")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile project(':project-core-submodule')
    compile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.0.0'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.200'

    compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.1'
    runtime 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.1',
            // Uncomment the next line if you want to use RSASSA-PSS (PS256, PS384, PS512) algorithms:
            //'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.60',
            'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.1' // or 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-gson:0.11.1' for gson

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '29.0-jre'

    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

asciidoctor {
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    dependsOn test
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your db-name is the same for the database name and the instance name? Is your code work locally?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere They're not the same but I use db-name as a dummy name in this post - my choice of dummy names was quite poor! I've double checked the properties file and both instance and db name are correct. I've included the full stack trace, if it helps?

Comment: And yes, the code runs fine locally but only if I add spring.datasource.url, pointing it to my local db.

Comment: Can you also share your dependencies (in Maven or Gradle format)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sure - I've added the build.gradle file to the question, please see above.

Comment: I don't see anything strange... Except maybe Guava. I always had bad experience with this dependency...

Comment: It’s worth nothing that this is a submodule, using another submodule of the same Gradle project if that makes sense. Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: Maybe... But I think Gradle smart enough for managing this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was Google Guava that was causing this issue - I simply removed the dependency from my build.gradle file, did `gradle clean build` and then redeployed!